# Count the repeat of numbers from a number in a same cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I got a bit confusing situation with excel, I would like to give an example

the spreadsheet is with a number unique to the cell and column

`colA colB colC
101   102  103
201   202  203`

Now, I have to find the repeats like below from above range

`0 = 6 times
1 = 5 times
2 = 4 times
3 = 2 times`

I have tried with CountIf() family functions, tried various functions from Len() etc.

If somebody can help in it, please.

Comment: 2 appears 5 times in those cells, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the 0s:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN($A$1:$C$2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$C$2,0,"")))
```

adjust the ranges as needed, and change 0 to 1, 2 etc, or use cell references.

Answer (score 1):

In **D1** enter:

```
=LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A:C))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A:C),ROW()-1,""))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, gary's student, TEXTJOIN function has been removed from 2016, and concatenate didn't work, tried with function creation but it was too slow

Comment: You need a 365 subscription or Excel 2019 to use TEXTJOIN.